# How does Facebook create such a varying range of views in their app?

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout

The facebook android app has a infinite list of views. Now there is no definite structure of the layout of these views. Depending on the post, this layout can have any structure. I really doubt facebook has defined all these layout structures beforehand. Can anybody help me in understanding how they do this ?

Comment: You can try to find out with uiautomatorviewer.

Comment: @Ascorbin: Thanks for your reply, but as I understand uiautomatorviewer is a tool, which lets you inspect the UI of an application in order to find the layout hierarchy, and view the properties. What I want to know is how do i develop an application where the UI has a facebook like postwise-varying interface ?